# Diferenciar usuarios dentro de una app

Tags: firebase, ios, swift

Estoy tratando de hacer una app iOS en la cual necesito que la app permita realizar distintas acciones dependiendo del usuario logueado.

Necesito saber como puedo hacer para que la app detecte que tipo de usuario es al realizar el login (si es un administrador o si es un cliente comun, quienes tendran distintas funcionalidades dentro de la app); y que asi, segun el usuario logueado, me permite o no realizar diversas acciones.

Para el login estoy usando firebase authentication.

No se si debo crear un backend, o existe alguna api que pueda usar.

Comment: Hola Diego, te sirvio la respuesta de abajo ? si es asi la puedes marcar como correcta ? gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones

1. Usar 1 Segue que conecte con un UIViewController que tenga un Container y dentro del UIViewController instanciar el UIViewController del container dependiendo del valor de isAdmin.
2. Si usas Segues directos desde un UIButton por ejemplo, cambia esto e implementa el @IBAction del UIButton, de esta manera dentro del action valida que tipo de usuario es y luego acciona el PerformSegue(withIdentifier: "NOMBRE_SEGUE_DESEADO", sender: nil (O un objeto que quieras pasar como parámetro))

Luego si necesitas hacer alguna inyección de dependencias o inicializar valores de los objetos en tu UIViewController destino implementa la función: prepareForSegue(...) y haz el tratamiento de los datos ahí dependiendo del destination.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de cada userID guardas el valor `isAdmin : Boolean` , cuando ingresas a la app, en el callback de success cuando te logueas haces una busqueda bajo ese nodo y chequeas que el campo `isAdmin` sea true o false, si es true lanzas X funcionalidad, si es false lanzas Y funcionalidad

```
UserID
|___ nombre: String
|___ email: String
|___ isAdmin: Boolean
```

Puede que cada vez que registres a un usuario no sepas si es admin o no, para eso seteas siempre que se registre un usuario nuevo como false.

Luego desde la consola puedes buscar su ID y ponerlo manualmente como true para hacerlo admin.

Comment: El problema es que mi app tiene dos segues, supongamos un segue X y un segue Y. Como debo hacer para leer el atributo isAdmin y que mi app implemente el segue correspondiente segun el valor de isAdmin?

Comment: Mi app tiene dos segues: un segue X y un segue Y. Necesito saber como hacer para que implemente el segue correspondiente según el valor que lea del atributo isAdmin. Por ejemplo, si isAdmin = true, haga el segue X, sino, que haga el segue Y